# List $wp_admin_bar menu items (debug)

Tags: wp-debug

I would like to dump the content of the `$wp_admin_bar` object in order to remove some menu items with the `remove_menu()` method.

What is the suggested way to do it without printing anything on the website?

I have enabled `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` in `wp-config.php`.
I was thinking about printing it in `debug.log`

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) and [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse_debug_toolbar' );
function wpse_debug_toolbar() {
    global  $wp_admin_bar;
    error_log( print_r( $wp_admin_bar, true ) );
}
```

Note that when using `print_r()` we've set the second parameter `$return` to `true` so that the results are returned and not echo'd.